# Unexpected javascript function behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

What I want is to add a loader bar to my `HTML`, while my method does some time consuming `AJAX` calls and `DOM` manipulation.

The problem is, that `show()` method won't show the loader bar until the `AJAX` calls are done, how do I fix this?

I want to force the `show()` method, then do `AJAX` calls and `DOM` stuff, then force the `hide()` method.

Method doing `AJAX` calls:

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
   $('#display-loader').show();
   // ajax and dom manipulation
   $('#display-loader').hide();
});
```

**EDIT:** Seems like there's some misunderstanding as to what my problem is. If I change my code to this:

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
   $('#display-loader').show();
   // ajax and dom manipulation
});
```

It still won't SHOW the loader bar, untill the `AJAX` methods are done, it's like it skips the `show()` method, does `AJAX` stuff, and then calls the `show()` afterwards.

All the `AJAX` calls have `async` set to `false`. I have 5 `AJAX` calls, and each `AJAX` call relies on the data fetched from the previous call, I have no way to set the `async` to `true`, is there a way to get around this, and force the `DOM` to display the image, and then do `AJAX` calls?

Comment: You're going to need to call `hideLoader` from the `success` callback of your ajax function.

Comment: Why u don't call $('#display-loader').show(); instead of showLOader(); and tehn inside the ajax--> success: funciont(){  $('#display-loader').hide(); }

Comment: Ajax is (or should be) asynchronous!!!

Comment: Per your recent edit, are you using `async: false` in your AJAX options? If so, the AJAX call will not allow the redraw and you won't see the visibility change

Comment: @Ian yes I have edited my post, explaining that i have async set to false, is there a way around this you reckon? without changing async, because it doesn't seem like a possibility at the moment.

Comment: @cnh1991: Nope. If it's blocking, it blocks the DOM updates as well.

Comment: @cnh1991 Technically, you could use `$('#display-loader').show(); setTimeout(function () { /* YOUR AJAX STUFF */ $('#display-loader').hide(); }, 25);`, but I wouldn't recommend it and it messes up the flow of things. Is there a reason why you can't change to `async: true`?

Comment: @Ian my 2nd ajax call relies on the 1st, and the 3rd relies on the 2nd and so forth. And it works with your timeout function, however the .gif image i use as the loader, freezes up, I'm aware it's probably because of the async false, but no way to fix this?

Comment: @cnh1991 Then use the callbacks of the AJAX calls (like `.done()`, `.fail()`, and `.always()`) and use AJAX the way it should be. There should be no problem using the result of `$.ajax()` (a jQuery `$.Deferred`) to accomplish this sequence

Comment: @cnh1991 Here's an example that could be reorganized to work better with repetition: http://jsfiddle.net/kdQkd/

Comment: I'm gonna refactor my code, thanks for your help @Ian, you've been a great help. If you post as answer, I will mark as correct. :) again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `hideLoader()` within AJAX `success` function, to hide after ajax operation. As `AJAX` is asynchronous, so in your code `hideLoader()` execute before finish ajax call and done dom stuff.

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
   showLoader();
   $.ajax({
     ....
     success: function() {
          hideLoader();
     } 
   });
});
```

according to @Esailija [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087490/unexpected-javascript-function-behaviour/18087540#comment26474527_18087540) to hide after complete callback do like:

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
   showLoader();
   $.ajax({
     ....,
     success: function(){

     },
     complete: function() {
         hideLoader();
     }
   })
});
```

Comment: The loader should be hidden in the `complete` callback (fired in both error and success cases), not just success.

Comment: Btw, the promise equivalent of `complete` is `.always()`

Comment: You can also remove the unnecessary anonymous function and just use `complete: hideLoader`

Answer (score 1):

you can do next:

```
showLoader();
$.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : url,
   data : postData,
   success : function (returnData) {

   },
   error : function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   },
   complete : function (){
       hideLoader();
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend maybe the following way:

```
$.ajax({
  .....
}).done(function () {
  hideLoader();
});
```

This will insure the loader goes away. If your ajax isn't successful then the success callback will never be reached and then the loader will stay on the page.

But it depends on the scenario. You can also just put it in your error callback.

Comment: Why put it in both? You can use the `.always()` method. And you might as well use `.done(hideLoader)` or `.always(hideLoader)`

Comment: that's why i didn't recommend it as my first option.

Comment: It was just some extra help in case the .done wasn't what he was looking for.